# Flutter installs SDK Tools repeatedly, even though they exists

Tags: flutter, sdk, platform-tools

My flutter app keeps installing SDK repeatedly even though it exists. I'm using vs code, I don't have android studio installed.

The app build was working before and all of a sudden stopped when I added a new dependency(I think).
There are no errors in flutter doctor but I get this error when I want to build the apk:

```
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform-Tools in C:\src\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform-Tools accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 34.0.1)".
Warning: Package "com.android.repository.impl.generated.v2.RemotePackage@5f80efaa" (platform-tools) should be installed in
"C:\src\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools\platform-tools" but it already exists.
Installing in "C:\src\commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest\cmdline-tools\platform-tools-3" instead.
```